# How to overcome the following error I am getting while I create a drop down attribute and assiging some value to it in magento?

Tags: magento

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`magento`.`eav_attribute`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type`
>   (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE ), query was: INSERT INTO `eav_attribute`
>   () VALUES ()

I am using the following code to add options to a dropdown attribute:

```
function addAttributeOption($attribute_code, $attribute_value) {
    $attribute_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

    $attribute_id = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
    $attribute = $attribute_model->load($attribute_id);

    $attribute_table = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

   foreach($options as $option) {
        // checking if already exists
        if ($option['label'] == $attribute_value) {
$optionId = $option['value'];
                return $optionId;
        }
    }

    $value['option'] = array($attribute_value,$attribute_value);
    $result = array('value' => $value);
    $attribute->setData('option',$result);
    $attribute->save();
}
```

What is this error and how to overcome this?

Comment: Would you mind trimming the code a bit? This doesn't seem like the smallest code you need for the error. Also, we need more information about the table structure.

Comment: Hey, thank you I found the solution to the problem.......I was calling function with  null arguments.So the exception was raised.